# One-To-One Entity Framework Code-First Mapping With Composite Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to create a one-to-one relationship on already defined entity properties? I've got the following entities:

```
public class Asset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public int OwningCustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer OwningCustomer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAsset
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } // Primary key 0
    public int AssetId { get; set; }    // Primary key 1
    public int CustomerAssetStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerAsset represents various states of ownership of an asset. Although the same AssetId can exist multiple times in this table, there will only ever be one instance where CustomerAssetStatusId = 1. In order to have quick access to the asset's current owner, I also maintain OwningCustomerId in the Asset table.

I would like to have a navigation property from Asset to CustomerAsset called OwningCustomerAsset. This is a one-to-one relationship. Unfortunately, I don't know how to define it since the foreign key fields are already defined in Asset. Typically, I would create a relationship like this on Asset:

```
HasRequired(e => e.OwningCustomerAsset).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("OwningCustomerId", "AssetId"));
```

Of course this results in the following error: "Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'OwningCustomerId' was already defined."

How can I tell EF that OwningCustomerId/AssetId is the foreign key to CustomerAsset?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your schema, I suggest making asset ownership a property of the asset itself and not of the customer-asset relationship.  Having a non-nullable FK field from `Asset` to `Customer` (e.g. `Owner_CustomerID`) enforces the "one owner only" constraint and the owner can be easily loaded from `CustomerAsset.Asset.Owner` (or whatever you choose to name it).  This schema change will greatly simplify your queries.

Furthermore, this will allow you to add a navigation property to `Customer` that references all owned assets; `Customer.OwnedAssets`, for example

Update:

Also add navigation property `Asset.OwningCustomerAsset` (or whatever you wish) from `Asset` to `CustomerAsset` using the new `Owner_CustomerID` field by way of compound FK `( AssetId, Owner_CustomerId )` and resulting navigation property

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've actually considered that. It does simplify some parts of my app. However, I've simplified my post a bit. There are other fields that my view returns that simplifies other things. For example, when supporting a customer and searching by asset name, the parent customer also wants the current owner's asset name to appear in his search results along with his. Having the one-to-one relationship really simplifies that since I can navigate ca => ca.OwnerCustomerAsset.Name.

Comment: a hybrid approach might be the best solution, then - have the Owner FK in Asset reference a CustomerAsset instead of a Customer

Comment: Actually my existing answer already does this - the FK would hold a CustomerId and Asset obviously already has its own ID, so the new Owner_CustomerID field can be used as a FK to Customer as well as part of a compound FK to CustomerAsset along with AssetId

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. I can configure a OwnerCustomerAsset navigation property on Asset using OwnerCustomerId and AssetId as my key. Then I'll always have quick access to the current owner's asset info when querying CustomerAsset...ca => ca.Asset.OwnerCustomerAsset.Name. Unfortunately, there are other "computed" fields in my desired view. Let me think it over to see if this approach can actually fulfill my requirements without having to use a hybrid approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still run into the same problem trying to create this composite key relationship. I've edited the post to simplify the explanation of the issue...which was really the same issue as before.

Answer (score 0):

Since I came down this road needing a navigation property on the other end (which I don't need anymore), I was stuck with the one-to-one mindset. The following gets me what I want:

```
HasRequired(e => e.OwningCustomerAsset).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e =>  new { e.OwningCustomerId, e.AssetId });
```

Comment: Ugh, I don't think it's possible to do what I want. There is a circular reference. I thought I could drop the FK relationship of OwningCustomerId/AssetId manually after DB creation. However, EF is still smart enough to see the circular relationship during SubmitChanges().